Why is nothing being rendered when I try to draw a cylinder in WebGL?
I am trying to draw a cylinder in WebGL and I feel like I am getting close, but it doesn't currently render anything even though I feel like there are no issues. Here is my code:
Javascript:
var gl;
var gl;
var vertices = [];
var indices = [];
var r = 0.5;
var height = 1.0;
var numSegs = 30;
var modelMatrix;
var projectionMatrix;
var program; 
var viewMatrix;

window.onload = function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    for (let i = 0; i < numSegs; i++) {
        var theta = (i / numSegs) * 2 * Math.PI;
        var x = r * Math.cos(theta);
        var y = r * Math.sin(theta);

        vertices.push(x, y, -height / 2);
        vertices.push(x, y, height / 2);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numSegs; i++) {
        indices.push(2 * i, (2 * i + 1) % (2 * numSegs), (2 * i + 2) % (2 * numSegs));
        indices.push((2 * i + 1) % (2 * numSegs), (2 * i + 3) % (2 * numSegs), (2 * i + 2) % (2 * numSegs));
    }

    vertices.push(0, 0, -height / 2);
    vertices.push(0, 0, height / 2);

    for (let i = 0; i < numSegs; i++) {
        indices.push(vertices.length / 3 - 2, (2 * i) % (2 * numSegs), (2 * (i + 1)) % (2 * numSegs));
        indices.push(vertices.length / 3 - 1, (2 * i + 1) % (2 * numSegs), (2 * (i + 1) + 1) % (2 * numSegs));
    }

    //  Configure WebGL

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader"); // Assign to program variable
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    modelMatrix = mat4.create();
    viewMatrix = mat4.create();

    render();
};

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    var fov = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
    var aspect = gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height;
    var zNear = 0.1;
    var zFar = 100.0;

    mat4.translate(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -5.0]);

    mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix"), false, projectionMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelMatrix"), false, modelMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "viewMatrix"), false, viewMatrix);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

HTML5:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
void
main()
{
    //gl_Position = vPosition*projectionMatrix*modelMatrix*viewMatrix;
    mat4 matrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * matrix * vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cylinder.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>


Any insight would be appreciated.
In the shader code, I originally was multiplying matrices in the wrong order as you can see in the commented out code, and it ended up making the shape come out wrong, but after changing the order of multiplication, nothing is rendered.

It seems to me that multiplication can't be completed, because: 1) viewMatrix x modelMatrix = 4x4 matrix, which is alright, but 2) projectionMatrix x matrix x vPosition makes it 4 x 4 matrix (the multiplication of the first two), and then that leaves you with 4 x 4 to be multiplied with a 1 x 4 matrix / vector, which goes against the rules of matrix multiplication. Are there any errors or exceptions in the console?

There is not any errors in the console. It is also strange because before, when I was using the commented out code, it would render, but instead of drawing a cylinder, it was just a very narrow oval.

Is anything rendered if you change this: gl_Position = projectionMatrix * matrix * vPosition; to this: gl_Position = vPosition * projectionMatrix * matrix;? It would help us debug, if you were to post a minimal, reproducible example, preferably as a stack snippet.
